# How to disable autofix project build configuration

Tags: android-studio, android-build

I'm using [mainframer](https://github.com/gojuno/mainframer) to build project.

Android Studio 3.3 Preview after every restart says

`The IDE updated the following run configuration: someConfiguration`

and really changes it: it adds new build step: Gradle build. It causes double building of project.

How to disable this autofixing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [comment #3 in Android Studio bug 77840239](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77840239#comment3): This feature can be disabled with a custom vmoption (`-Dgradle.ide.gradle.run.configuration.fix.enabled=false`)